# C# WebBrowser.Print() does not print specific HTML files when the IMG image is not exists

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to print from a very basic C# Form application using the WebBrowser control Print() method, but with a specific HTML file, nothing seems to happen.
The printing works fine with other HTML files, and the only difference, is that the problematic html file contains an image with a non existing image. I would expect to ignore the non existing image and print the file, but no printing, not even an exception happens.

How could I somehow manage the printing even if the file has non existing references, such as image? What workarounds do i have?

The browser emulation is already set to IE11, and already tried ExecWB, nothing seems to work.

HTML: (image.jpg is not exists)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<BODY>
<div class="page">
<table class="table"><tbody><tr><td class="nobotpadding">
<div class="per-details">
<span class="med-text blue mr10">
test text
<img src="/img/image.jpg" alt="" width="14" height="14">
</span>
</div></td></tr></tbody></table>
</div></BODY></HTML>
```

C#: (Load and Print are different buttons on the form.)

```
public void Load()
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(localhtmlfile);
}

public void Print()
{
    webBrowser1.Print();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to reach the picture inside your Print mehtod and reach Exception if you cannot acces to it. If you can, you print the form

Comment: The problem is that i would like to print the html file with or without the image, possibly without changing the html file.

Comment: I think that will be difficult to unmodify the htmlfile. You can maybe check inside the method and if image isn't possible to find, you have another htmlfile without <img> and you print this one

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe do something like that:
htmlfilewithimg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<BODY>
<div class="page">
<table class="table"><tbody><tr><td class="nobotpadding">
<div class="per-details">
<span class="med-text blue mr10">
test text
<img src="/img/image.jpg" alt="" width="14" height="14">
</span>
</div></td></tr></tbody></table>
</div></BODY></HTML>
```

the htmlfilewithoutimg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<BODY>
<div class="page">
<table class="table"><tbody><tr><td class="nobotpadding">
<div class="per-details">
<span class="med-text blue mr10">
test text
</span>
</div></td></tr></tbody></table>
</div></BODY></HTML>
```

and inside your C# code, you try to go inside your picture to see if there is a file with the name of the picture and if there isn't a picture, you use the second htmlfile
like :

```
public void Load()
{
    try
    {
        Path.GetFileName("img/img");
        webBrowser1.Navigate(htmlfilewithimg);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(htmlfilewithoutimg);
    }
}

public void Print()
{
    webBrowser1.Print();
}
```

Comment: The problem is, the html file is not coming from me, therefore i cannot edit it. One possible solution is to filter for images, i figured out that too, but then i will neither print the existing images, unless i do some nasty check to distinguish local or web images.